# Change dimensions for a batch raster in Python

Tags: python, geotiff-tiff, dimensions

I have over 8000 GeoTIFF files and want to adjust their dimensions (not individual cell size) into 1062*1652 (columns*rows). I only know do it one-by-one under QGIS, but are there any packages I can use in Python to automate the work?

Answer (score 1):

In QGIS, execute the tool manually, press Ctrl+Alt+H, copy the code and adapt. Then execute the code in the python window of QGIS.

I used Warp, with the "Additional command line parameter" `-ts 100 100` to resample to 100*100 pixels.

Try this:

```
import os
infolder = r'C:\GIS\data\tempdata\infolder' #The folder where you keep the rasters
output_folder = r'C:\GIS\data\tempdata\outfolder' #The folder to store the resampled rasters. This must not be a subfolde to infolder

for root, folder, files in os.walk(infolder):
    for file in files: #For all files in infolder
        if file.endswith('.tif') and 'ras' in file.lower(): #Find the files with .tif extension and with the string ras in the filename. You can add or remove conditions here
            fullname = os.path.join(root, file) #Concat path and filename
            print(f"processing: {file}")
            output_file = os.path.join(output_folder, file.replace('.tif', '_resampled.tif')) #Rename the output
            processing.run("gdal:warpreproject", 
                {'INPUT':fullname,'SOURCE_CRS':None,'TARGET_CRS':None,
                'RESAMPLING':0,'NODATA':None,'TARGET_RESOLUTION':None,
                'OPTIONS':'','DATA_TYPE':0,'TARGET_EXTENT':None,
                'TARGET_EXTENT_CRS':None,'MULTITHREADING':False,
                'EXTRA':'-ts 100 100','OUTPUT':output_file})
```

[image]